# Python loop through Dataframe 'Series' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas version 0.19.0, I have a dataframe with compiled regular expressions inside.  I want to loop over the dataframe and see if any of the regular expressions match a value.  I can do it with two for loops, but I can't figure out how to do it so that it'll return a same sized dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

inp = [{'c1':re.compile('a'), 'c2':re.compile('b')}, {'c1':re.compile('c'),'c2':re.compile('d')}, {'c1':re.compile('e'),'c2':re.compile('f')}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
for i,v in df.items():
  for a in v:
    if (a.match('a')):
      print("matched")
    else:
      print("failed")
```

This fails:

```
[a.match('a') for a in [v for i,v in df.items()]]
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'match'

What I want:

```
[a.match('a') for a in [v for i,v in df.items()]]
              c1                                         c2
0   <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>     None
1   None                                                None
2   None                                                None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the `applymap` method. See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html?highlight=applymap) for more info.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.match('a'))
```

Output:

[image]